# SQL server Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a trigger heres the question

Assume the Owner Table contains a column called TotalRental that represents the total rental fee for all slips rented by that owner. Write the code for the following triggers following the style shown in the text

a.When inserting a row in the MarinaSlip table, add the rental fee to the total rental for the appropriate owner

heres my sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_rentalfee
ON MarinaSlip
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE Owner
SET TotalRental = TotalRental + RentalFee
FROM Owner INNER JOIN MarinaSlip ON Owner.OwnerNum = MarinaSlip.OwnerNum
WHERE owner.OwnerNum = MarinaSlip.OwnerNum

END
GO
```

as you can tell im new to sql the problem is that when i insert a row it changes all the rows in the table not just the one i want 
please explain whats wrong and how can i fix it Im using microsoft sql server 2012 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the INSERTED table to select only the rows which have been inserted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_rentalfee
ON MarinaSlip
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE Owner
SET TotalRental = TotalRental + RentalFee
FROM Owner INNER JOIN MarinaSlip ON Owner.OwnerNum = MarinaSlip.OwnerNum
INNER JOIN INSERTED ON owner.OwnerNum = INSERTED.OwnerNum

END
GO
```

If you examine your `SELECT` statement a bit closer, the `INNER JOIN` links the two tables together but your `WHERE` clause is not doing any filtering. If you were the server, how would you read your statement? Update all rows where the owner number matches the owner number in marina slip.

[TechNet: Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot you dont want to know how long i was working on this

Answer (score 0):

You should use INSERTED table and also make sure your query can handle many rows inserted at one time:

```
UPDATE Owner
SET TotalRental = TotalRental + insT.SumRentalFee
FROM Owner 
INNER JOIN 
(select OwnerNum, sum(RentalFee) as SumRentalFee 
        from INSERTED 
        group by OwnerNum) as insT
 ON Owner.OwnerNum = insT.OwnerNum
```